# xargs -I behaviour

Tags: bash, xargs

A variable `var` contains multiple arguments, each split by a new line.

```
echo "$var" | xargs -I % echo ABC %
#Results in:
#ABC One
#ABC Two
#ABC Three
```

However, when omitting `-I` and the `%` characters, I get the following:

```
echo "$var" | xargs echo ABC
#Results in:
#ABC One Two Three
```

I've once read {} would substitute for the current argument (like find does), but that does not happen. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The usual behavior of `xargs` is to paste as many arguments as possible onto the command line of any command it runs, iterating 'till it's done them all.  When used this way, it's a solution to the problem of command line length limitations.

But when you specify the `-I` option, it runs the command on each argument *individually*, one-at-a-time. I don't think that's completely obvious in the documentation of the Linux `xargs -I` option but that's what they mean.

```
-I replace-str
       Replace occurrences of replace-str in the initial-arguments with
       names read from standard input.  Also, unquoted  blanks  do  not
       terminate  input  items;  instead  the  separator is the newline
       character.  Implies -x and -L 1.
```

Comment: `Also, unquoted  blanks  do  not terminate input items; instead the  separator is the newline character.` — this is central to understanding the behavior. Without `-I`, `xargs` only sees the input as a single field, since newline is not a field separator. With `-I`, suddenly newline _is_ a field separator, and thus `xargs` sees three fields (that it iterates over). That is a real subtle point, but is explained in the `man` page quoted.

Comment: @DanielAndersson That's true, but that's not what the OP found confusing.

Comment: @DanielAndersson : Thank you! This nuance was instrumental for me to understand the behaviour I saw with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55608069/why-is-xargs-exit-code-different-based-on-the-presence-of-i-option

Comment: I have evidence of the effect of `-I` with the help of a wrapper script which clearly shows two invocations when `-I` is used : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55608069/why-is-xargs-exit-code-different-based-on-the-presence-of-i-option/55608265#55608265

Answer (score 0):

If you use GNU Parallel instead of xargs you can control which behaviour you want:

```
# 1 line at a time
echo "$var" | parallel echo ABC {}
# Many lines at a time (divided by # cpu)
echo "$var" | parallel -X echo ABC {} 
# Many lines at a time (not divided)
echo "$var" | parallel -Xj1 echo ABC {}
```

It takes literally 10 seconds to install GNU Parallel:

```
wget pi.dk/3 -qO - | sh -x
```

Watch the intro videos to learn more: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1

Comment: -- *Literally.* Anyway, this question is about xargs. Not parallel. Parallel is not posix

Comment: *"[GNU parallel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_parallel) is free software, written by Ole Tange in Perl"*